# Python ctypes usage passing pointers

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I am trying to call functions from a C library in python 2.7. I am rather confused by most tutorials or information I've found so far.

The C function takes in 3 doubles (labeled h, k, l) and 2 pointers to a double (*p, *q) to iteratively solve the two doubles, initialized with 0.0 for simplicity. The function returns nothing, it just uses the pointers to modify the values of p and q.

My current code reads:

```
import ctypes
path = '/foo/bar.so'
_lib = ctypes.CDLL(path)
_lib.solve.argtypes = (ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

def py_solve(h, k, l):
    global _lib
    p, q = ctypes.c_double(0.0), ctypes.c_double(0.0)
    _lib.solve(ctypes.c_double(h), ctypes.c_double(k), ctypes.c_double(l), ctypes.POINTER(p), ctypes.POINTER(q))
    return float(p), float(q)
```

I get:

```
'TypeError: must be a ctypes type'
```

on the line calling _lib.solve(...) in my py_solve function. Maybe this would be simpler by using ctypes' byref() function but I am unsure how to do that as well. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `ctypes.POINTER` takes an argument that is a ctypes *type*.  When you use it in the line

```
_lib.solve.argtypes = (ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
```

that's exactly what you're doing, since ctypes.c_double is a *type*.

When later you call it like this:

```
ctypes.POINTER(p)
```

the argument isn't a type but an *instance* of a type - an already initialized variable of type ctypes.c_double.

All you need to do is to create a pointer to the already initialized variables p and q.  Just replace `ctypes.POINTER(p)` with `ctypes.byref(p)`.

Comment: Thanks. Very well explained, things make sense now.

Comment: Note that `byref` doesn't create a ctypes pointer per se, unlike `ctypes.pointer` or instantiating a pointer type. `byref` directly references the buffer of a ctypes object, which is more efficient than creating a ctypes pointer.

Comment: See also [this documentation section](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference) on this very point.